# Resample a raster to the grid of another unaligned raster using GDAL/pktools

Tags: gdal, resampling

Is there a way to resample a raster to the grid of another raster using Bash utilities (GDAL or pktools), if both of the rasters do not necessarily have their origins aligned (and without an intermediary origin alignment step)?

Here are some example file `gdalinfo` output. Reference:

```
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (-70.000496031746025,15.000496031746032)
Pixel Size = (0.000992063492063,-0.000992063492063)
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=DEFLATE
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( -70.0004960,  15.0004960) ( 70d 0' 1.79"W, 15d 0' 1.79"N)
Lower Left  ( -70.0004960,   5.0004960) ( 70d 0' 1.79"W,  5d 0' 1.79"N)
Upper Right ( -60.0004960,  15.0004960) ( 60d 0' 1.79"W, 15d 0' 1.79"N)
Lower Right ( -60.0004960,   5.0004960) ( 60d 0' 1.79"W,  5d 0' 1.79"N)
Center      ( -65.0004960,  10.0004960) ( 65d 0' 1.79"W, 10d 0' 1.79"N)
```

Source (to be reprojected):

```
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (43.999861111111102,4.000138888888890)
Pixel Size = (0.000277777777778,-0.000277777777778)
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  43.9998611,   4.0001389) ( 43d59'59.50"E,  4d 0' 0.50"N)
Lower Left  (  43.9998611,   2.9998611) ( 43d59'59.50"E,  2d59'59.50"N)
Upper Right (  45.0001389,   4.0001389) ( 45d 0' 0.50"E,  4d 0' 0.50"N)
Lower Right (  45.0001389,   2.9998611) ( 45d 0' 0.50"E,  2d59'59.50"N)
Center      (  44.5000000,   3.5000000) ( 44d30' 0.00"E,  3d30' 0.00"N)
```

Basically, this is a question related to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/268119/how-can-2-geotiff-rasters-be-aligned-and-forced-to-have-same-resolution-in-pytho) just without using Python or QGIS.